# What are the factors affecting in burning Calories?

Tags: running, calories, treadmill

I'm running in treadmill everyday for 10 minutes with speed of 6kmph. The treadmill shows the amount of calories burnt is around sixty. My question is only Time,speed and distance determines the calories burnt or there are other factors too?

Comment: related: [Energy expenditure (calories burned) equation for running](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/15608/energy-expenditure-calories-burned-equation-for-running)

Comment: related: [Calories burn rate calculation — scientific studies](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18730/calories-burn-rate-calculation-scientific-studies?rq=1)

Comment: related: [How to calculate calories burned while running](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24553/how-to-calculate-calories-burned-while-running?rq=1)

Comment: related: [Calculate burned calories (Running) without heart rate](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/25176/calculate-burned-calories-running-without-heart-rate?rq=1)

Comment: related: [Is it possible to measure calorie burn from heart rate alone?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12435/is-it-possible-to-measure-calorie-burn-from-heart-rate-alone?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many various factors. Actually, there are so many, that every calorie burnt calculation is an approximation.

The first and most obvious factor is - does your treadmill include your BMR in its calculations? ([BMR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basal_metabolic_rate)) Your weight, age, VO2max, the intansity of the exercise (your heart rate), bloodsugar level, the temperature... Sometimes its even hard to determine if something is actually a factor - it would require making separate studies on that subject.

The baseline is - almost everything you can do to measure burnt calories is only an approximation. Those approximations can be wildly inaccurate. But you have to know - why do you even need the number? If you want to measure your trainign progress or motivate yourself for training, aim for more "material" indicators and goals. Try to run further, longer and faster. Try different exercises, running distances and intensities. Since youre asking about burning calories, I assume you want to lose weight. My advice is - dont rely on calorie calculations, they are very inacurrate in both intake and expenditure. Check out the great questions on weightloss that can be found on this site - they should be of help.