# Kettlercise, calories burnt

Tags: calories, heart-rate

I never heard of Kettlercise before so looked at some videos.
Kettlercise doesn't look very demanding.  Less heavy breathing than my 12 minute/mile pace jogs.
There are very impressive claims about how much calories Kettlercise can burn, like 657 calories in 45 minutes (24yo F, 5'6", of unknown weight)
I tried using the calories burnt as function of HR formula* on this page:

[Is it possible to measure calorie burn from heart rate alone?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12435/is-it-possible-to-measure-calorie-burn-from-heart-rate-alone?rq=1)

That formula comes up with numbers I think are credible for my calorie burn when I am jogging (*I have a pretty good estimate of my real VO2MAX).

But the HR that would be required for a 24yo female to get to 657 cal/53 minutes, requires all kinds of extreme values in the formula above. VO2max = 50, 70 kg, avg HR = 195.  Do those numbers make sense(??)  Is the formula that inaccurate?

Or would I be right to think that Kettlercise energy expenditure is probably being over-hyped?

Comment: *Kettlebell* exercises are probably too complex of movements to fit into that formula. Plus there's some degree of anaerobic work going on with these types of movements.

Comment: Do some snatches and swings with a 53lb kb, and then check that effort against a 12 minute mile.

Comment: How did you obtain the value for your "good estimate of your real VO2max"?

Comment: Thanks for replies.                           .....It looks very boring, costs money,  I have history of RSI in my forearms, so Kettlebells probably not good for me.  I just wondered if those calorie expenditure values could be true for something that doesn't look that tiring..... I had my VO2MAX lab-tested 10 yrs ago.  Assuming an avg % decline for my age, my VO2Max should still be around 44-I forget the units, but anyway, close enough.  My husband had his VO2MAX done 10 yrs ago & again 3.5yrs ago (both lab -treadmill etc) and his hadn't changed at all in the intervening time.

Answer (score 1):

Exercises with kettlebells can be as hard as barbell work, sprinting or high end sport activities if done correctly.

'Kettlecise' sounds like a group class which is typically aimed at anybody. So it might not be suitable for someone already quite fit.

Try it out and then increase the weights as necessary. A 8kg kettlebell in a class feels a lot different to a 24kg one.

Much like a jog and a sprint are essentially the same but completely different.